# Reducing the height of horizontal listview - xamarin forms

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, horizontallist

I am trying to get a horizontal listview scrolling horizontally having some numbers(0-23) as items in it.

I am getting the listview as horizontal but the height of the listview is not getting wrapped to the content. I tried using RelativeLayout with xConstraint, yConstraint, width and heightConstraint, I tried changing the parameter values in it but the listview disappears all the times I change the values.

```
ListView lv = new ListView
        {
            SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.None,
            ItemsSource = items,
            Rotation = 270,

            ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
            {

                Label label = new Label()
                {
                    Rotation = 90,
                    TextColor = Color.Black,
                    HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                    FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, new Label())
                };
                label.SetBinding<User>(Label.TextProperty, indexer => indexer.Time);

                return new ViewCell
                {
                    View = new StackLayout
                    {
                        Children =
                            {
                            label
                        }
                    }
                };
            })
        };

        RelativeLayout rLayout = new RelativeLayout();

        rLayout.Children.Add(lv,
                             xConstraint: Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
                              {
                                  return (parent.Width / 0.5) - 30;
                              }),
                             yConstraint: Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
                              {
                                  return (parent.Height / -0.5) + 3;
                              }),
                             widthConstraint: Constraint.Constant(60),
                             heightConstraint: Constraint.RelativeToParent((Parent) =>
                              {
                                  return (Parent.Height / 10);
                              })
        );

        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {
                rLayout
            }
        };
```

I am new to xamarin, may be the way I am going is wrong. If so please suggest me the right one.. But as of total I want a horizontal listview having only numbers as items and I want the height to be wrapped to the content.

Please any help would be appreciable.. thanks in advance..

Comment: For such simple scenario I would probably use `<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">` inside `<ScrollView>`. Create custom control based on `StackLayout` with `ItemsSource` property.

Comment: Perhaps you could try to make use of the [carousel view](https://blog.xamarin.com/flip-through-items-with-xamarin-forms-carouselview/). Not really sure if it fits your use case though.

Comment: thanks for your answer @EgorGromadskiy it help me.. sorry for late reply..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make auto height of items inside the listview then you have to use `HasUnevenRow="true"` in your XAML file.

Example:

```
    <ListView x:Name="SomeList" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding ...}" SeparatorVisibility="None">
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
              <ViewCell.View>
                <Label HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="Blue" Margin="0,5,0,5" Text="{Binding ....}" FontSize="Small" HeightRequest="35"/>
              </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Prabhat.. I tried that even but the result is same as explain in my question..